# Error related to undefined variable

Tags: javascript

What's wrong with this code? I get:

TypeError: older is undefined
(10 out of range 3)

but older is defined at the beginning: `var older = people[0]`

```
function person(name, age) {
    this.name=name;
    this.age=age
}

function foo() {
    var older10 = function(people) {
        var older = people[0];

        for (var index = 1; index < 10; index++) {
            if (people[index].age > older.age) {
                older = people[index]; // error here
            }
        }
        return older;
    };

    var array = [];
    array[1] = new person("Paul", 23);
    array[2] = new person("Jim", 24);
    array[3] = new person("Sam", 84);
    array[4] = new person("Rob", 54);
    array[8] = new person("Karl", 19);
    array[9] = new person("", 0);

    var older = older10(array);

    if (older.name === "Sam") {
        console.log("ok");
    }
}
```

Comment: You never define `people[0]` (`array[0]`), hence `var older = people[0];` assigns `undefined` to `older` and `older.age` fails. Don't hardcode indexes, lengths (`index < 10`) like this. Just add the items to the array in the order you want them and iterate over the array. You get the current length with `people.length`. Read more about arrays: https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Guide/Predefined_Core_Objects#Array_Object

Comment: your `//error here` is in the wrong place.. it's actually the line above (if condition) that causes it, the call to `older.age`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You never define `array[0]` (referred to as `people[0]` within the `older10(array)` function call) so older is set to undefined!

Comment: It's true but when I fix, I get: *TypeError: people[index] is undefined*

Comment: maybe because array[5](and 6, 7) are not present ?